# How do I identify the different wires on RPLidar?

Tags: arduino, lidar

I bought an RPLidar A1M8-R6 from the following site: https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1125.html?tracking=585c2ddea9c83

I am trying to connect RPLidar to Arduino so I could get information on the degrees and distance detected by the Lidar. I was following the instructions from the video on the following site: https://dronebotworkshop.com/getting-started-with-lidar/

My problem is that I am unable to figure out which wires to connect to Arduino. I was trying to follow the video but the colors of the wires in the video and their orientation is not the same in the product I have. Can somebody please help me identify the wires? I'm trying to figure out which one is Ground, 5v, Tx, Rx, Motoctl, Vmoto and vcc. Thank you very much! I'm attaching the picture of the wires here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `How do I identify the different wires on RPLidar?` ... by reading the datasheet

Answer (score 2):

Like [jsotola mentioned](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/22665/how-do-i-identify-the-different-wires-on-rplidar#comment36770_22665), the way to find information on a thing is to look at its datasheet. From [the datasheet](https://download.slamtec.com/api/download/rplidar-a1m8-datasheet/3.2?lang=en) (warning: direct download, found on the bottom-right of [this page](http://www.slamtec.com/en/Support#rplidar-a-series)):

[image]

So, comparing your picture to the datasheet, it looks like:

```
Signal     | Color
--------------------
TX           Yellow
RX           Green
VCC_5V       Orange
GND          White
GND_MOTO     Black
CTRL_MOTO    Blue
5V_MOTO      Red
```

You're really going to want to read the datasheet, because that's where you're going to get all the information about baud rate, packet format, parameter settings, voltages, power consumption, etc.